# VBA Excel Userform error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am creating a userform to update company data. The first control in my form is a combo box (which is code) and the rest are text box. Now I need to use vlookup to lookup my first control and the rest of the text box will be automatically updated with the code that I key in in my combo box. But the system shows error 1004. Can someone help me with this? Below is my combo box code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_code_AfterUpdate()
    'check if value exist
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), Me.ComboBox_code.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Code"
        Me.ComboBox_code.Value = ""
        Exit Sub

    End If
'lookup value based on first combobox
    With Me
        .TextBox_outlet = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 2, 0)
        .TextBox_invoice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 3, 0)
        .TextBox_sales = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 4, 0)
        .TextBox_comm = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 5, 0)
        .TextBox_gst = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 6, 0)
        .TextBox_netsales = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.ComboBox_code), Sheet1.Range("Code"), 7, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox.Value` gives the selected index, but you can get the selected item with [`.List(.ListIndex)`](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/12/21/working-with-combo-boxes-form-control-using-vba/)

```
Private Sub ComboBox_code_AfterUpdate()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Sheet1.Range("Code").Resize(, 1).Find(Me.ComboBox_code.List(Me.ComboBox_code.ListIndex), , , xlWhole)

    If c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Code"
        Me.ComboBox_code.ListIndex = -1
    Else
        Me.TextBox_outlet.Text = c(, 2)
        Me.TextBox_invoice.Text = c(, 3)
        Me.TextBox_sales.Text = c(, 4)
        Me.TextBox_comm.Text = c(, 5)
        Me.TextBox_gst.Text = c(, 6)
        Me.TextBox_netsales.Text = c(, 7)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also test for any actual combobox value selection made by the user

a `Select Case` block could be appropriate:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_code_AfterUpdate()
    Dim codeRow As Long
    Dim codeRng As Range

    Set codeRng = Sheet1.Range("Code")
    With Me
        Select Case True

            'check if user selected a value
            Case .ComboBox_code.ListIndex = -1
                MsgBox "No Code selected!", vbCritical
                .ComboBox_code.Value = ""

            'check if value exist
            Case WorksheetFunction.CountIf(codeRng.Resize(, 1), .ComboBox_code.Value) = 0
                MsgBox "Incorrect Code", vbCritical
                .ComboBox_code.Value = ""

            Case Else
                codeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(.ComboBox_code.Value, Sheet1.Range("Code"), 0) 'lookup value based on first combobox
                .TextBox_outlet = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 2)
                .TextBox_invoice = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 3)
                .TextBox_sales = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 4)
                .TextBox_comm = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 5)
                .TextBox_gst = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 6)
                .TextBox_netsales = codeRng.cells(codeRow, 7)
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, you may also want to use the `ComboBox_code_Change()` event handler instead of `ComboBox_code_AfterUpdate()`: the former would fire at every combobox change (i.e. selection) while the latter would fire only once the combobox is no longer the active control i.e. you must wait for the user to leave the control

Comment: @Janice, did you get through it?

Comment: @Janice, any chance to get feedback from you?